# always get this error 'express' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: express, npm

I have tried many solutions like configuring environment variable, install express and express generator locally and globally
    `npm install express`
    `npm install -g express-generator.`
when I use `express testapp` or any express command it throws an error:

> 'express' is not recognized as an internal or external command

I am using window 10. 
What can cause this error
and how to resolve it?